# Variables in media query

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm trying to set a css variable to another css variable in a media query. But I'm not seeing the change I would have thought. If I look in the Chrome dev tools, it is using the --ratio-alt variable. But the result on screen looks more that it is just showing the fonts at 100%.

I have tried changing the order of the media query, but no luck there.

```
:root {
    --font-size: 100%;
    --ratio: 1.333;
    --ratio-alt: 1.68;

    --h4: calc(var(--font-size) * var(--ratio));
    --h3: calc(var(--h4) * var(--ratio));
    --h2: calc(var(--h3) * var(--ratio));
    --h1: calc(var(--h2) * var(--ratio));
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
    :root {
      --ratio: --ratio-alt;
    }
}
```

I expect that all font-sizes would calculate for the ratio-alt above 40em width. But that isn't happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap `--ratio-alt` in `var()` when assigning it to `--ratio`, inside your `@media` query:

```css
:root {
  --font-size: 100%;
  --ratio: 1.333;
  --ratio-alt: 1.68;
  --h4: calc(var(--font-size) * var(--ratio));
  --h3: calc(var(--h4) * var(--ratio));
  --h2: calc(var(--h3) * var(--ratio));
  --h1: calc(var(--h2) * var(--ratio));
}

@media (min-width: 40em) {
  :root {
    --ratio: var(--ratio-alt);
  }
}
```

Comment: It was the ```var()``` around ```-ratio-alt``` I was missing. There is no need to reassign the values in the media query.

Comment: @user, that's news to me. I'll test some more. Glad I could help, though. I'll update my answer once I find relevant documentation on how and why it works the way it does.

Comment: You're correct. When updating a CSS var, all rules using it get updated. Which means the `:root` rules (outside of `@media`) change while `@media` is active. Thanks for pointing it out. Cheers!

Comment: Just starting to learn CSS variables, so that's perfect to know.